# Different memory leaks in different hardware architecture

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, valgrind

I am dealing with memory leak in C code these days. I am amazed to see the different memory leaks in different hardware architecture.

The following is the leak summery shown by valgrind in 64 bit architecture:

```
                LEAK SUMMARY:
      ==4064==    definitely lost: 1,600,192 bytes in 7 blocks
      ==4064==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==4064==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==4064==    still reachable: 3,217,416 bytes in 2,155 blocks
      ==4064==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      ==4064== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown. 
      ==4064== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
      ==4064== 
      ==4064== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
       ==4064== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

And following is for 32 bit architecture

```
     LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==29607==    definitely lost: 1,600,048 bytes in 4 blocks .
    ==29607==    indirectly lost: 456 bytes in 33 blocks.
    ==29607==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
    ==29607==    still reachable: 96 bytes in 12 blocks.
    ==29607==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
    ==29607== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
    ==29607== To see them, rerun with: --show-reachable=yes
```

What can be the reasons for it.

Comment: The output is for a normally exiting program? If it exists when failing, it may fail in different places. As crashes have usually much to do with memory management, it may crash a little bit before or after in each architecture, hence the big difference. Note also that 64bit usually uses much more memory than 32 bits (i.e. pointer size, etc.)

Comment: Does it mean if i could manage to prevent memory leak in any of the architecture then  it will work for the both the architectures?

Comment: A correct program does not leak :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't know the exact details and all, but if you leak some data that was based on the size of some type, the leak will result in larger amounts of bytes for a 64 bit, compared to a 32 bit.

For example, if you leak this piece of data:

```
// arr holds an array of 10 pointers
int *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
```

The leak will result larger on a 64 bit (compared to 32bit) because the size of `int *` is platform dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there are some bugs in the libraries on your 64 bit machine?

Alternatively, some of your code might cast pointers into 32 bit integers and back, causing mayhem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like an array overrun or writing data via an invalid pointer you can expect that the layout of the memory on the different machines will be different.  So if you do:

```
void * foo(void) {
     char str[100];
     void * p = malloc(100);
     memset(str, 0, 111);
     /* ... more code ... */
     return p;
}
```

Then you could imagine that both str and p are on the stack.  The order that they are layed out may differ, as well as how many extra bytes of may be allocated on the stack to pad them, so the error in length of the memset may lose the reference to the newly allocated memory, or it may not.  Depending on lots of other things the memset error may or may not be noticed by valgrind, but I needed to use a simple case that was easy to comprehend.

This may or may not be similar to what is happening, but I think that it demonstrates the type of thing that could happen.